# Use routing and controllers from another bundle on Symfony2

Tags: symfony, entity, bundle, symfony-routing

I am using a Custom Bundle built by me and I have installed FOSUserBundle.
Inside my bundle I have `UserEntity` which has its Controller and it's routing with the prefix: `/admin/user`. I want the route `admin_user_show` to get the action from the `FOSUserBundle:Profile:show`

This is the code to routing.yml

```
admin_user_show:
path:     /{id}/show
defaults: { _controller: "CMSBundle:User:show" }
methods:  GET
```

I change it to this but I get an error:

```
fos_user_profile_show:
path:     /{id}/show
defaults: { _controller: "FOSUSerBundle:Profile:show" }
methods:  GET
```

This is the error I get:

```
The "FOSUSerBundle" (from the _controller value "FOSUSerBundle:Profile:show") does not exist or is not enabled in your kernel! Did you mean "FOSUserBundle:Profile:show"?
```

How can I include FOSUserBundle into my Bundle?
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that you have a typo in your routing:
`FOSUSerBundle:Profile:show` instead of `FOSUserBundle:Profile:show`
(note that in your case the S in User is capital)

Comment: Thank you very much! As it seems everything was ok, except my typo.